# Radio button keeps loading

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a product builder and I have found a template on codyhouse that looks like it will do the job. The only issue is that the button to select just stays on loading and doesn't progress.

This is the link to the website. https://codyhouse.co/demo/product-builder/index.html

Once the radio button is selected, it keeps loading. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am out of my depth. I suspect this is an issue with JS but I am not sure.

[image]

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    function ProductBuilder( element ) {
        this.element = element;
        this.stepsWrapper = this.element.children('.cd-builder-steps');
        this.steps = this.element.find('.builder-step');
        //store some specific bulider steps
        this.models = this.element.find('[data-selection="models"]'); 
        this.summary;
        this.optionsLists = this.element.find('.options-list');
        //bottom summary 
        this.fixedSummary = this.element.find('.cd-builder-footer');
        this.modelPreview = this.element.find('.selected-product').find('img');
        this.totPriceWrapper = this.element.find('.tot-price').find('b');
        //builder navigations
        this.mainNavigation = this.element.find('.cd-builder-main-nav');
        this.secondaryNavigation = this.element.find('.cd-builder-secondary-nav');
        //used to check if the builder content has been loaded properly
        this.loaded = true;
        
        // bind builder events
        this.bindEvents();
    }

    ProductBuilder.prototype.bindEvents = function() {
        var self = this;

        //detect click on the left navigation
        this.mainNavigation.on('click', 'li:not(.active)', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            self.loaded && self.newContentSelected($(this).index());
        });

        //detect click on bottom fixed navigation
        this.secondaryNavigation.on('click', '.nav-item li:not(.buy)', function(event){ 
            event.preventDefault();
            var stepNumber = ( $(this).parents('.next').length > 0 ) ? $(this).index() + 1 : $(this).index() - 1;
            self.loaded && self.newContentSelected(stepNumber);
        });
        //detect click on one element in an options list (e.g, models, accessories)
        this.optionsLists.on('click', '.js-option', function(event){
            self.updateListOptions($(this));
        });
        //detect clicks on customizer controls (e.g., colors ...)
        this.stepsWrapper.on('click', '.cd-product-customizer a', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            self.customizeModel($(this));
        });
    };

    ProductBuilder.prototype.newContentSelected = function(nextStep) {
        //first - check if a model has been selected - user can navigate through the builder
        if( this.fixedSummary.hasClass('disabled') ) {
            //no model has been selected - show alert
            this.fixedSummary.addClass('show-alert');
        } else {
            //model has been selected so show new content 
            //first check if the color step has been completed - in this case update the product bottom preview
            if( this.steps.filter('.active').is('[data-selection="colors"]') ) {
                //in this case, color has been changed - update the preview image
                var imageSelected = this.steps.filter('.active').find('.cd-product-previews').children('.selected').children('img').attr('src');
                this.modelPreview.attr('src', imageSelected);
            }
            //if Summary is the selected step (new step to be revealed) -> update summary content
            if( nextStep + 1 >= this.steps.length ) {
                this.createSummary();
            }
            
            this.showNewContent(nextStep);
            this.updatePrimaryNav(nextStep);
            this.updateSecondaryNav(nextStep);
        }
    }

    ProductBuilder.prototype.showNewContent = function(nextStep) {
        var actualStep = this.steps.filter('.active').index() + 1;
        if( actualStep < nextStep + 1 ) {
            //go to next section
            this.steps.eq(actualStep-1).removeClass('active back').addClass('move-left');
            this.steps.eq(nextStep).addClass('active').removeClass('move-left back');
        } else {
            //go to previous section
            this.steps.eq(actualStep-1).removeClass('active back move-left');
            this.steps.eq(nextStep).addClass('active back').removeClass('move-left');
        }
    }

    ProductBuilder.prototype.updatePrimaryNav = function(nextStep) {
        this.mainNavigation.find('li').eq(nextStep).addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
    }

    ProductBuilder.prototype.updateSecondaryNav = function(nextStep) {
        ( nextStep == 0 ) ? this.fixedSummary.addClass('step-1') : this.fixedSummary.removeClass('step-1');

        this.secondaryNavigation.find('.nav-item.next').find('li').eq(nextStep).addClass('visible').removeClass('visited').prevAll().removeClass('visited').addClass('visited').end().nextAll().removeClass('visible visited');
        this.secondaryNavigation.find('.nav-item.prev').find('li').eq(nextStep).addClass('visible').removeClass('visited').prevAll().removeClass('visited').addClass('visited').end().nextAll().removeClass('visible visited');
    }

    ProductBuilder.prototype.createSummary = function() {
        var self = this;
        this.steps.each(function(){
            //this function may need to be updated according to your builder steps and summary
            var step = $(this);
            if( $(this).data('selection') == 'colors' ) {
                //create the Color summary
                var colorSelected = $(this).find('.cd-product-customizer').find('.selected'),
                    color = colorSelected.children('a').data('color'),
                    colorName = colorSelected.data('content'),
                    imageSelected = $(this).find('.cd-product-previews').find('.selected img').attr('src');
                
                self.summary.find('.summary-color').find('.color-label').text(colorName).siblings('.color-swatch').attr('data-color', color);
                self.summary.find('.product-preview').attr('src', imageSelected);
            } else if( $(this).data('selection') == 'accessories' ) {
                var selectedOptions = $(this).find('.js-option.selected'),
                    optionsContent = '';

                if( selectedOptions.length == 0 ) {
                    optionsContent = '<li><p>No Accessories selected;</p></li>';
                } else {
                    selectedOptions.each(function(){
                        optionsContent +='<li><p>'+$(this).find('p').text()+'</p></li>';
                    });
                }

                self.summary.find('.summary-accessories').children('li').remove().end().append($(optionsContent));
            }
        });
    }

    ProductBuilder.prototype.updateListOptions = function(listItem) {
        var self = this;
        
        if( listItem.hasClass('js-radio') ) {
            //this means only one option can be selected (e.g., models) - so check if there's another option selected and deselect it
            var alreadySelectedOption = listItem.siblings('.selected'),
                price = (alreadySelectedOption.length > 0 ) ? -Number(alreadySelectedOption.data('price')) : 0;

            //if the option was already selected and you are deselecting it - price is the price of the option just clicked
            ( listItem.hasClass('selected') ) 
                ? price = -Number(listItem.data('price'))
                : price = Number(listItem.data('price')) + price;

            //now deselect all the other options
            alreadySelectedOption.removeClass('selected');
            //toggle the option just selected
            listItem.toggleClass('selected');
            //update totalPrice - only if the step is not the Models step
            (listItem.parents('[data-selection="models"]').length == 0) && self.updatePrice(price);
        } else {
            //more than one options can be selected - just need to add/remove the one just clicked
            var price = ( listItem.hasClass('selected') ) ? -Number(listItem.data('price')) : Number(listItem.data('price'));
            //toggle the option just selected
            listItem.toggleClass('selected');
            //update totalPrice
            self.updatePrice(price);
        }
        
        if( listItem.parents('[data-selection="models"]').length > 0 ) {
            //since a model has been selected/deselected, you need to update the builder content
            self.updateModelContent(listItem);
        }
    };

    ProductBuilder.prototype.updateModelContent = function(model) {
        var self = this;
        if( model.hasClass('selected') ) {
            var modelType = model.data('model'),
                modelImage = model.find('img').attr('src');

            //need to update the product image in the bottom fixed navigation
            this.modelPreview.attr('src', modelImage);

            //need to update the content of the builder according to the selected product
            //first - remove the contet which refers to a different model
            this.models.siblings('li').remove();
            //second - load the new content
            $.ajax({
                type       : "GET",
                dataType   : "html",
                url        : modelType+".html",
                beforeSend : function(){
                    self.loaded = false;
                    model.siblings().removeClass('loaded');
                },
                success    : function(data){
                    self.models.after(data);
                    self.loaded = true;
                    model.addClass('loaded');
                    //activate top and bottom navigations
                    self.fixedSummary.add(self.mainNavigation).removeClass('disabled show-alert');
                    //update properties of the object
                    self.steps = self.element.find('.builder-step');
                    self.summary = self.element.find('[data-selection="summary"]');
                    //detect click on one element in an options list
                    self.optionsLists.off('click', '.js-option');
                    self.optionsLists = self.element.find('.options-list');
                    self.optionsLists.on('click', '.js-option', function(event){
                        self.updateListOptions($(this));
                    });

                    //this is used not to load the animation the first time new content is loaded
                    self.element.find('.first-load').removeClass('first-load');
                },
                error     : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    //you may want to show an error message here
                }
            });

            //update price (no adding/removing)
            this.totPriceWrapper.text(model.data('price'));
        } else {
            //no model has been selected
            this.fixedSummary.add(this.mainNavigation).addClass('disabled');
            //update price
            this.totPriceWrapper.text('0');

            this.models.find('.loaded').removeClass('loaded');
        }
    };

    ProductBuilder.prototype.customizeModel = function(target) {
        var parent = target.parent('li')
            index = parent.index();
        
        //update final price
        var price = ( parent.hasClass('selected') )
            ? 0
            : Number(parent.data('price')) - parent.siblings('.selected').data('price');

        this.updatePrice(price);
        target.parent('li').addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected').parents('.cd-product-customizer').siblings('.cd-product-previews').children('.selected').removeClass('selected').end().children('li').eq(index).addClass('selected');
    };

    ProductBuilder.prototype.updatePrice = function(price) {
        var actualPrice = Number(this.totPriceWrapper.text()) + price;
        this.totPriceWrapper.text(actualPrice);
    };

    if( $('.cd-product-builder').length > 0 ) {
        $('.cd-product-builder').each(function(){
            //create a productBuilder object for each .cd-product-builder
            new ProductBuilder($(this));
        });
    }
});
```

Changing the JS/Css, but no luck.

Comment: The link I posted is to a working version on their website. The one you download does not work correctly. - Tim

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].  If you get stuck, post a ***[mcve]*** of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: And please don't tag Java when you mean JavaScript. They're two different languages.